# simpleexcel : I get an error when I changed the host

Tags: php

Recently I have changed my host. On the previous host, every thing was ok, but now on the new host I get following error..

Please direct me to the host so I can solve this problem ASAP???

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Document namespace isn't a valid Excel XML 2003 Spreadsheet' in /home/jalali/public_html/admin/SimpleExcel/Parser/XMLParser.php:198 
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/jalali/public_html/admin/SimpleExcel/Parser/XMLParser.php(305): SimpleExcel\Parser\XMLParser->parseDOM(Object(SimpleXMLElement)) 
#1 /home/jalali/public_html/admin/@dmin.php(28): SimpleExcel\Parser\XMLParser->loadFile('../archive/1371...') 
#2 {main} thrown in /home/jalali/public_html/admin/SimpleExcel/Parser/XMLParser.php on line 198
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `XMLParser.php`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar where does it say `XML` extension not installed